# Android POST JSON to server PHP

Tags: php, android, json

I'm having some problems finding and using the JSON object that my app Posts to my server.
Here's my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = exmaplePrefs.getString("jsonString", "cant find json");
       // String json = "{\"twitter\":\"test\",\"country\":\"test\",\"name\":\"test\"}";

        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        String status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString();
        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (!status.equals("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error")){
            if(inputStream != null){
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);   
            }
            else{
                result = "Did not work!";
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("500 Error");

        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result;
}
```

..

```
    endGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                    //new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");    
                    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://rugbyone.net84.net/recieve_data.php");
        }
    });
```

..

```
private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

Below is the PHP. As you can see, I've tried various different ways but cannot find the JSON. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    /*  Database connection  */

     if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {  

     $data->msg = strrev($data->msg);
     $data = json_decode($_POST["json"]);
     echo json_encode($data);
     echo $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
}
     $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
     $json2 = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    // Lets parse through the JSON Array and get our individual values
    $parsedJSON = json_decode($json, true);
    var_dump($json);
    var_dump($parsedJSON);
    var_dump($json2);
    var_dump($data);


 ?>
```

Comment: What's your problem? Please explain and if you have error in log cat, please attach it in your question

Comment: what is the point of `$data->msg = strrev ...`? You replace `$data` on the next line anyways. And if you don't get anything form php://input, your client-side code isn't sending anything to PHP in the first place.

Comment: they are all ways that i found to 'grab' the json object but none work

Comment: @MarcB I tested the clientside but posting to this server  - http://posttestserver.com/data/2014/01/26/15.33.18171433763

and as you can see the json object is there...

Comment: @JackDuong no errors in logcat. I get OK 200! so the app is working correctly

Comment: @ChrisMowbray: So, I don't understand what is your issue? Because I tested your link, It work fine.

Comment: @JackDuong yes but thats not my server....this is http://rugbyone.net84.net/recieve_data.php

and i cannot see the json anywhere

Comment: Result: string(53) "{"twitter":"Jack","country":"VN","name":"Jack Duong"}"
array(3) {
  ["twitter"]=>
  string(4) "Jack"
  ["country"]=>
  string(2) "VN"
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "Jack Duong"
}
NULL
NULL
 
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: @JackDuong can you elaborate on this

Comment: @ChrisMowbray I think what he's saying is that you have some extra code being putout and therefore it breaks the JSON interpreter and is Malformed. To address this, call `die()` after you return your `json_encoded()` string.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i have removed all unwanted code and now have this>>>

<?php
 $json = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $parsedJSON = json_decode($json, true);
 var_dump($json);
 var_dump($parsedJSON);
 ?> 

still does not find the json object :(

Comment: The JSON will still be invalid, due to the fact that you're dumping 2 objects simultaneously and they aren't separated by a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just sending a raw post body to your PHP site.  Your PHP is expecting a post variable called json, but that is not defined in the Android code you provided.

You should use a NameValuePair like in this post:

[Apache HTTP Client, POST request. How to correctly set request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068346/apache-http-client-post-request-how-to-correctly-set-request-parameters)